# strcpy in java :(

Tags: java

I have an algorithm that reads from the stdout into a string variable called 'name' and then creates a string array that stores the name..I tried to do this in java but first, I don't know how to pass the name into the array. in C or C++, i could have just easily done this : strcpy(arr, name); but these are string types and there are no c_str() equivalent in Java that I have seen. Please, how do I do this?

```
      .... //codes are here...
      System.out.Println("enter your name and press enter:");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String name = null;
  try
    {
      name = br.readLine();
      String[] arr = new String[name.length];
       //wish this was C++;
        strcpy(arr.c_str(), name.c_str()); //how do you copy the name string to the arr   
                                           //string?

  }catch(IOException e)
     {
      System.out.Println(e.getMessage());
    }

    MyClass A = new MyClass(arr);
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a `String` array of all the characters in `name`?

Comment: why do you need string array if you do `readLine` only once - there is `String.toCharArray` and `System.arraycopy`

Comment: `strcpy(arr, name)` with `name` being user input sounds like suicide in C. I hope you can't break your programs that easily in Java.

Comment: `String[]` is an array of strings, analogous to `char**` in C. I think you're looking for an equivalent to `char*`. You could, I suppose, use a `char[]` or possibly one of the buffer classes, but for most applications, I would imagine any advantage would be dubious at best.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `String` after you read it from `System.in`? You probably don't need to copy the individual bytes. Just store a reference to the string somewhere.

Comment: The answer is that you think a `String` in Java is related to a `char` array like in C - it's not. It's an object and on top of that it's immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are completely mixing up stuff here.

Either the assignment `name = br.readLine()` will produce an error (because readLine() returns a `String` not a `String[]`) or the expression `name.length` will produce a compiler error because a `String` does not have a property `length` only a method `length()`

Secondly:

```
String[] arr = new String[name.length];
```

will create an array of `String` objects. It does **not** declare a String of length name.length.

If you really want to store the value read from the Reader into an array of String objects, can directly assign this:

```
String[] arr = new String[] { name };
```

Will create an array with one element, that contains the value of the name variable.

But I don't see why you would want to put that String instance into an array in the first place.

And last but not least: there is no need to copy the String you get around. You can safely work with that instance (e.g. return it from the method) because the `String` class is immutable in Java.

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't need to copy the string.

In C (and parts of C++) strings are represented as character arrays whose contents can be changed throughout the life of the program - hence the need for `strcpy`, partly so you can preserve string contents.

However, in Java strings are represented by the `String` class and instances are *immutable*, so the contents of a string cannot change througout the life of the program.  This means that once you've got a reference to a string you can pass it around to any other Java code and not worry about its contents getting changed.

So in your code example, once you have read the "name" string you can just pass that value to the `MyClass` constructor:

```java
System.out.println("Enter your name and press enter:");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String name = br.readLine();
MyClass a = new MyClass(name);
```